# How to improve reindexing magento 2.3.3 [EE]?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-enterprise, reindex

How to improve reindexing Magento 2.3.3 [EE]?

60K products

It takes around 20min to reindex full.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Change all indexer mode to 'Update by Schedule'
2. Changing the batch size can help you optimize indexer running time.
   https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/indexer-batch.html
3. If customer indexer is there, make sure the logic is optimized.

Thanks!

> nithincninan@gmail.com,
> +919895382293